# why is ether.js .on event listener not firing when event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethers.js

### Problem

I'm coding a bot for pancakeswap predictions (https://bscscan.com/address/0x18b2a687610328590bc8f2e5fedde3b582a49cda). The abi and everything is set up correctly. But I just can't figure our why my .on listener is not working. I made an old version of this script a few months back and that worked perfectly fine. Can the smart contract block other people from seeing and recieving events? Or am I doing something wrong. I've been trying to solve this for a few hours now and I went through a lot of stack overflow questions and documentation so any input would be helpful. Thanks. The scripts remains blocked looking like its waiting for an event but when a new round of pancakeswap predictions begins the listener isn't triggered.

### Code

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

const result = dotenv.config();
if (result.error) {
  throw result.error;
}

const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const pspBnbAbi = require("../abis/pspBnbAbi.json");
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  `https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/`
);

/**
 * PSP BNB smart contract
 */
const contract = new ethers.Contract(
  process.env.PSP_BNB_SMART_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  pspBnbAbi,
  provider
);

/**
 * Burner wallet
 */
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.WALLET_KEY, provider);

/**
 * Connect wallet to smart contract for writing transactions
 */
contractWithWallet = contract.connect(wallet);

const main = async () => {
  console.log(await contract.currentEpoch());

  contractWithWallet.on("StartRound", (epoch) => { <-- This isn't firing at all
    console.log("round started")
  })

};

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

i never use `ether.js` . i am using `web3.js`. use `websocket` with a paid provider like getblock.io , ankr.com or others. by subscribing to a topics.
read here https://www.coinclarified.com/p/3-ways-to-subscribe-to-events-with-web3-js/

```js
let options = {
    address: ['address-1', 'address-2'],    //Only get events from specific addresses
    topics: [
       // topic hash
    ]       
};

let subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', options,(err,event) => {
    if (!err)
    console.log(event)
});

subscription.on('data', event => console.log(event))
subscription.on('changed', changed => console.log(changed))
subscription.on('error', err => { throw err })
subscription.on('connected', nr => console.log(nr))
```